# apiary REST Service definition

Tags: apiary

I use apiary for my REST service definitions and I will response a request parameter - in the case at the bottom I will resonse the {area} request parameter. Is there any syntax in the a.piary editor to do this? ({area} and $area does not work)

```
## StandbyService Phone API [/standby/phone/{area}]

### Phone[GET]

+ Response 200 (application/json)

    [
        {
            "number": "00436760815",
            "area": "{area}"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to disappoint you, but it's currently not possible. Nevertheless, it's interesting idea, so we would be happy if you could share it on https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues with some details about your use case.